# version compatability og ojdbc6 ojbdbc14 and jdbc versions

Tags: jdbc, oracle12c

What are the oracle and driver version I can use for Java 6?

Comment: Are you looking for [this FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/jdbc-faq-090281.html#01_03_1)?

Comment: ojdbc6 is for Java6, ojdbc14 is for Java 1.4. (and ojdbc7 for Java7, ojdbc8 for Java8, etc). So you need ojdbc6 if you are still on Java 6. But why are you still using Java 6?!